# Creating a DB table dynamically for each user that signs up in a website, could be a solution for this?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just out of curiosity, as it would solve most of my problems like querying multiple fields and comparing multiple tables (the spaghetti entanglement). 
How safe is it? Is it bad practice or is it ok. If it's fine What are the precautions to take with regards to safety.

The problem is in the relation of 3 tables:  'users', 'friends', and 'posts'.

users:

- id
- name
- lastname
- email
- ...etc

friends:

- id(int)
- userid1(int)
- userid2(int)
- friendship_requested_by(int)
- accepted (varchar)
- blocked (int)
- blocked_by(int)
- befriended_on(date)

posts:

- post_id(int)
- userid(int)
- post_text(text);
- ...etc

I'm having problems in querying the 'friends' TBL getting the users ids that are friends with the logged user, because there are 2 fields to compare 'user_id1' and 'user_id2' then pull all the results in  "desc' order from the posts table has been a nightmare or I must be really rusty in mysql. My shortcut being, if I could have a table/db for each user then there would be just a table for friends with only one 'friend_id', would be much simpler I suppose.

The spaghetti:

```
  function getPosts($email){
                 $myid = $this->getStudentId($email);
                 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id1 FROM friends
                        UNION 
                        SELECT DISTINCT user_id2 FROM friends
                       WHERE (user_id1 = ? AND accepted = ? AND blocked = ?)
                           OR (user_id2 = ? AND accepted = ? AND blocked = ?)";

                $query =  $this->db->query($sql,array($myid,'yes','no',$myid,'yes','no'));

                if($query->num_rows() > 0){
                    foreach ($query->result() as $r){

                           //echo "<br>my id1: ".$student_id1;
                         echo "<br> rows : ". $query->num_rows;
                         echo "<br> Amigos : ". $r->user_id1;
                          echo "<br> Amigos : ". $r->user_id2;

                        return $this->getPostByStudentId($r->user_id1,$r->user_id2);


                    }
                }


             }



function getPostByStudentId($student_id1,$student_id2){
             $this->db->where('user_id',$student_id1);
             $this->db->where('user_id',$student_id2);
             $this->db->order_by('post_id','desc');
             $sql = $this->db->get('posts');
             if($sql->num_rows() > 0){

                 return $sql->result();
             }

         }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most databases have limits on how many tables it could be

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There are no considerable up-sides.

Comment: Extremely bad practice, normalize your data.

Comment: This is a tough question to ask since it involves opinion.

Comment: @Lashane It's a project for a university, so it would be a table for each student. I know it sounds terrible lol. but i'm kind of feeling drained, and it seems a much easier solution.

Comment: It would be more useful to create a new 'database' for each user. You can then move them to different servers if the current server gets 'busy' due to them. Also if you delete a database 'cos of 'inactivity' - no one else is affected. (according to suggestions from an internet search). Sounds sensible to me.

Comment: @jovan I'm  having lot's of problems sorting out a query. it seems simple enough though but not in practice

Comment: I notice that this idea seems to pop up in many heads of mostly inexperienced programmers, who after a while all seem to regret it.

Comment: @BenFortune I already have normalized my tables, but the relation through id's I'm having some problems with some multiple queries that never seem to end.

Comment: Right.I'll explain my problem and what I'm trying to achieve, will edit the question

Comment: @RyanVincent nice, I will look into this option if i cannot sort my entanglement ;)

Comment: Run [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) to figure out why they are slow, probably it's just handicapped by the lack of proper indexes, or unintentional cartesian products, etc.

Comment: Just Edited the question and added my specific problem, I know there are lots of gurus in here that might see it as a very basic problem though, thanks for all the explanations and help.

Comment: What do `user_id1` and `user_id2` represent?

Comment: @AdamW "user_id1" is the user id of the user that requests friendship from "user_id2". "user_id1"  is the user logged in session viewing other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the reciprocal nature of the Friends table.  If Bob (UserID1) is friends with Jim (UserID2), should you also have another record for Jim(UserID1) is friends with Bob(UserID2).  Now you have two records, but at least you don't have to select distinct from both fields.

I would refactor the database and replace the friends table is a frendship table and drop the userIDs and then have a user_friendship bridge table that holds the userID and FrienshipID.  You then only need to query the bridge table to find all the friendships for a single user.

Comment: Right It works, I used a join query and joined the 3 tables. Now I just need to include the user logged in the query as well. Thanks so much for your help. :D

Answer (score 5):

Not a great idea. As your database grows, you're going to end up with a slower and slower performance as indexing isn't as fast when you need to search across multiple tables.

If you end up needing to get lots of user information (for example, you want a report on how many users you have and what their email addresses are), all of a sudden you're `join`ing lots of tables (as many users as you have) together or making hundreds of queries.

It would be better to keep everything in fewer tables and keep data logically together, rather than keeping users logically together.

It might seem tempting, but it's poor database design.

You'll want to understand database normalisation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization